# Importance of the power of t-test in the case when $H_0$ is rejected

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I know that $\beta$ (type II error) is the probability that the null hypothesis is false, but it is not rejected. The power of the test is defined $1−β$. I still thought that the power of the test is important only in the case when $H_0$ is not rejected. However my statistical software compute the power of the test also in the case when $H_0$ is rejected. In my opinion information about power of the test in the case when $H_0$ is rejected is useless. Is it true? Or is information about power in the case when $H_0$ is rejected usefull for some kind of statistical decision.

Comment: My apologies for nitpicking, but your first sentence is mis-worded. $\beta$ is the probability that the null hypothesis will not be rejected *given that it is false*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you stated, power is about the probability of something happening.  It's the probability that the null will be rejected given that it is false.  In a future experiment, where someone attempts to replicate you, power is completely independent of whether your particular experiment rejects the null.  So, it's useful information either way.

In fact, I'd argue it's less useful when you don't reject the H0... but primarily due to misinterpretation.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer I understand your argument "In a future experiment, where someone attempts to replicate you, power is completely independent of whether your particular experiment rejects the null." However I am not sure what do you mean with the last sentence "n fact, I'd argue it's less useful when you don't reject the H0... but primarily due to misinterpretation." Please, could you explain this more detailed?

Comment: If you report high power and you didn't reject the null then people will tend to think that the null is true.  That's unlikely.  What's likely is that the effect is small.  However, consider the converse, a lower powered experiment where you do reject the null.  Your effect size must be quite large and it suggests you have very strong evidence.  In this case, what's likely true, is that you have an over estimate of the true effect and it's actually lower, perhaps substantially.  I think the former is more problematic.  It's better to quantify effects than just think of them as there or not.